# AC wiring indoor to outdoor

Tags: wiring

I have voltas ac but the outdoor is of other brand and it has only 3 wires phase netural and ground were to connect the control wire i tired to rem``ove phase and connect control'wire but it blows away the fuse

Comment: tell us:  the equipment you are working on, what you are doing, and show us pictures of the wires.

Comment: It does not usually matter if it is inside or outside, the wires are connected the same way.  Blowing of a fuse/breaker usually means a short, hot/phase touching ground/neutral.  Pictures will help us see what is happening.

Comment: Of course, plugs and sockets must not get wet.